# How to upload media files(images or mp3 songs ) to java server from android client

Tags: java, android, upload, media

hi guys i am new to android and currently trying to learn few things about it.
i am building an app in which i can upload some media files (images from the gallery or music from the mobile ) to the server running on my PC , which is written in java .

I have established the client server connection , but i do not know how to transfer media files !!
some good link and some guidance would be very helfull 
thanks

here is the EDIT

my server code code

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.*;

public class wow {

    ServerSocket serSock;
    Socket sock;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Writer output = null;
        // File file = new File("write.txt");
        // output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        //String clientSentence;

        try {
            wow cs = new wow();
            cs.startServer();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    public void startServer() throws Exception {
        String clientSentence;
        Writer output = null;
        File file = new File("write.txt");
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        try {
            serSock = new ServerSocket(6789);
            System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
            sock = serSock.accept();

            System.out.println("Connections done");


            BufferedReader inFromClient =
                    new BufferedReader(new
                            InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            // tarea.setText(clientSentence);
            output.write(clientSentence);
            System.out.println(clientSentence);
            output.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

this code just receives a message from the client and displays it

Comment: What kind of server is running on your PC? An HTTP server?

Comment: @GregKopff no its a java server

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't actually _mean_ very much.  Is this "Java server" written by you?  Can you edit your post with some details about your server please?

Comment: @GregKopff i have edited my post and posted my server code !

Comment: 1. Have you seen how your code is formatted in the question? To have people invest in you, please invest in making your code neat and tidy - ensure the indentation is correct and there aren't huge gaps (one blank line is enough to separate blocks). 2. You don't want to be using a `Reader` if you're trying to upload _binary_ data. You want to use a `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: @GregKopff thank you greg for your tips !

Comment: @GregKopff can i use HTTP server for the purpose of uploading ?
i mean how should i know which kind of server to use ?

Comment: yes you could use HTTP - have a look at Daniel Jonkers answer below for some pointers ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use servlets on the server and post the byte array of the files in Restful manner?

I would use the [httpclient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) library to do the http posting and the [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library to serialize the data into json.

Then on the server side I would just make [servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html) to accept the http posts your sending. Using netbeans or eclipse with the appropriate plugins (can't remember which ones, web developer tools(wdt) in eclipse I think) makes building servlets much easier as it sets up the doPost and doGet methods.